# Remove instances where nominal attribute = value (Weka GUI)

Tags: weka

I have a dataset with:

- 400 instances
- I have one nominal attribute `cluster` with values:

  - `cluster1`
  - `cluster2`
  - ...
  - `cluster10`

How do I remove instances where e.g. `cluster=cluster5`?  (using the GUI)

I was told to use the filter `weka.filters.unsupervised.instance.RemoveWithValues`, but it seems to only be able to remove **numerical** values below a certain *splitPoint*. I could of course use the Edit window, but notice I have 400 instances!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

weka.filters.unsupervised.instance.RemoveWithValues will remove nominal values. Note the field "nominalIndices" in the image below.  After selecting the index of the desired attribute, enter the index of the nominal value you would like to have removed. [image]

Comment: I was trying to put `cluster5` (the nominal value) directly into the `nominalIndices` field. I see I have to find in the explorer what the index is (which 2 in my case), and insert that. Thanks!